SELECT from two tables, JOIN without relationship, repeating value in one col or the other
I have two SELECT statements that acquire the correct data from two different tables.
-- 1: 
SELECT employee_id FROM employees
WHERE city = 'London';

-- returns employee_id = 5, 6, 7, 9

-- 2:
SELECT category_id FROM categories
WHERE category_name ILIKE 'dairy%';

-- returns category_id = 4 

I have an employees_categories table I'd like to populate with the following, based on the above criteria:
    | employee_id | category_id |
    | ----------- | ----------- | 
    |           5 |           4 |
    |           6 |           4 |
    |           7 |           4 |
    |           9 |           4 | 

I could use
INSERT INTO employees_categories (
    employee_id, category_id
) VALUES (5,4), (6,4), (7,4), (9,4);

But I was hoping to create a CTE based on the two SELECT statements at the top, so I can use it for INSERT INTO (automate the entire process in one query).
I am having trouble figuring out how to pair results from the two SELECTs, since employee_id or category_id potentially repeat (as shown), and there is no common relationship between the two tables they are selected from.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Can you be sure the category query will only return one row? Since there's no relationship between the two tables, you might as well do an insert from select and hard code 4 as the category id.

Could you make a temp table of cities and category names?

Definitely thought about hard-coding for this result, but it wouldn't scale or respond accurately for future queries.  Re: Temp table, I was already hoping to make a CTE with this info, and then INSERT using that... two CTEs, maybe?

How do you know which employees and categories go together? Expanding your example might help.

I could show output from a more detailed SELECT query for context, but the problem only allows retrieving id numbers, so it would solely be descriptive. Point taken, though, thanks

There's no rule saying the ON clause of a JOIN must use both tables... but be careful if you don't or you may be surprised at what you get.
SELECT employee_id, category_id
FROM employees
JOIN categories ON category_name ILIKE 'dairy%'
WHERE city = 'London';


Wow I'm so impressed, I didn't know you could do that!  I didn't even have to refine the syntax for it to produce the exact results I needed, either - how often does that happen?  Remarkable!

I'd CROSS JOIN instead, and put the ILIKE condition in the WHERE clause (since it's not a join condition.)

@jarlh can you elaborate on what you mean by that?  Perhaps create another answer?

@AveryFreeman, employees CROSS JOIN categories WHERE category_name ILIKE 'dairy%' AND city = 'London', same result, more a matter of taste.
